# How to run an executable Java-File with Python?

Tags: java, python, executable

I've got an external program named "*program.exe*" and I want to run that by calling from Python. The point is, this executable was build with Java (I'm not the programmer).
By clicking this file in the file-explorer it runs without any problems, but with Python it failed yet.

I tried:

- os.system
- os.startfile (it's a Windows-machine)
- subprocess.Popen

Getting Error-messages like:

- FindClass failed
- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Seems it's a simple task but every attempt failed.
Some hints for me?

Comment: please share your python code and exact errors on each attempt otherwise it's too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution.** It has nothing to do with the fact, that the .exe-File was compiled with Java. The reason for the error was the missing parameter "cwd", which define the working directory.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C:\\Folder\\bin\\program.exe", cwd="C:\\Folder\\bin")
```

To export the answer from the Shell it's possible to try this:

```
import subprocess
ShellOutput=subprocess.Popen("C:\\Folder\\bin\\program.exe", cwd="C:\\Folder\\bin", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(ShellOutput.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8"))
```

Examples were evaluated with Python 3.6